# SecurityException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers

Tags: c#, winforms, security, com, reference

From a C# WinForm project, I want to call a .NET COM method that already exist. I've added the reference to the COM, but I can't get rid of the SecurityException "That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers".

Both projects are strongly named. I've added [assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers] at the top of the COM project, but it still crash when I try to call the public method.

What step did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Are they installed in the GAC?

Update: 2nd guess might be versioning issues.

Comment: Not in the GAC. How do I check for versioning issues? I've rebuilt the 2 projects but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I think they are meant to be in the GAC. Thats the point of APTCA, AFAIK IIRC (hehe).

Comment: I don't want/need them to be in the GAC. The point is the COM is working perfectly when called from VFP, but for a reason that escape me, a C# project can't call it. Seem strange to me that VFP doesn't have any security issue at all while the .NET project is judged as unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It's explained here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/psingh/CallingCOMComponentFromCSharp12022005231615PM/CallingCOMComponentFromCSharp.aspx